# S3 authentication inside lambda function / Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, playframework-2.0, aws-lambda

I have a scala play application which I am trying to run as a lambda function. It receives notification from s3 bucket for a new object and then acquires the object and works on it. It works fine when I run the S3 put test as well as to the point of acquiring bucket details from the s3 event. However it fails when I try to get the object based on the information in the event.

```
private val awsCredentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()
private val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentialsProvider)
private val bucketName = play.Play.application.configuration.getString("aws.s3.BUCKET")
val s3object = amazonS3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, objectKey))
```

and this

```
val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client()
```

But I get the below error.

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:139) 
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:134) 
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:95) 
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:60) 
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:46) 
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:35) 
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:339) 
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:279) at controllers.Main.getSourceBuckets(Main.scala:24) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:235) at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:249) at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:304)

Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration 
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:46) 
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:35) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:339) at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:279) 
    at models.TabSpaceFileParser$.downloadAllFileFromS32(TabSpaceFileParser.scala:62) 
    at controllers.ParserTask$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(ParserTask.scala:49) 
    at controllers.ParserTask$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(ParserTask.scala:34) at controllers.ParserTask.WithApplication(ParserTask.scala:60) 
    at controllers.ParserTask.exec(ParserTask.scala:34) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in the built.sbt file where the assembly contained the line

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".properties" => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".xml" => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".types" => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".class" => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".json" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case "Unwanted.Txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```

On removing

```
case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".json" => MergeStrategy.discard
```

The issue was resolved. Apparently it was discarding some important json configuration files from aws dependencies which was causing the above error.